# Create "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" for Magento

Tags: product-attribute, custom-options, validation

I want to create new "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" for attributes.

I can do this by reference link  [Edge ProductAttachments](https://github.com/outeredge/edge-magento-module-productattachments)

But now my query is How can I add custom text boxes,radio buttons in "Manage Label / Options" part ? See attached image for referance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change/add inputs by below files :

adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml

adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/attribute/js.phtml